# Django Models: Linking recipes and keeping track of quantities

Tags: python, django, sqlite

**Problem Description**

Suppose I have a database with multiple models running with a Django front-end.

One of the tables in the Inventory. The inventory consists of entries with the following specifications:

```
class InventoryItem(models.Model):
    item_name = models.TextField(max_length=10) #apple, orange, cilantro, etc...
    item_quantity = models.DecimalField(...)
```

The next model will be to describe what is made with those ingredients

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_name = models.TextField(...)
    product_description = models.TextField(...)
```

The `ProductItem` model also needs to keep track of the ingredients taken from inventory by specifying the `InventoryItem` and the quantity used from that inventory item used.

**Previous Experience**

In a previous experience, I have done something similar with EntityFramework in C# with MySQL. The way I achieved that was using another table/model called `RecipeElement`, where each one of those would be foreign-keyed to a `ProductItem` entry. The `RecipeElement` model looked like the following:

```
class RecipeElement(models.Model):
    inventory_item = models.ForeignKey(InventoryItem, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    quantity_used = models.DecimalField(...)
    product_item = models.ForeignKey(ProductItem, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

**The Issue**

My issue with that approach in Django is twofold:

1. How would I retrieve the `RecipeElement` entries associated with a `ProductItem` entry
2. How would the user input the `RecipeElement` entries and the `ProductItem` entries on one page. (The number of `RecipeElement`s for each `ProductItem` is not limited, but each `RecipeElement` is associated with only one `ProductItem`

I am using SQLite for the moment but plan to transfer to MySQL in the future, if that changes anything.

Comment: in the second issue you want to add a new `recipeElement` with a `ProductItem`?

Comment: More or less. Ideally, the user would be able to add a new `ProductItem` and specify all its `RecipeElement`s in one view @MauricioCortazar

Comment: you can get the object and use .`add(yourproductitemhere)` that is what you mean?

Comment: I just your comments to dig further into the documentation, and `.add`/`.create` are exactly what I need! Thank you! The documentation is found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/relations/).

Comment: I will edit my answer so if you want you can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retrieve all the `RecipeElement` for a `Product`  do something like:

```
ProductItem.objects.get(pk=1).recipeelement_set.all()
```

In the second issue you can add a `recipeElement` from a `product` using `.add()` or `create()` like:

```
ProductItem.objects.get(pk=1).recipeelement_set.add(your_recipe_element)
```